# Upload file to a specific Azure Storage container using Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

Right now I am working on an API that allows customers to upload their files to their own containers. I provide them with a container name and a SAS Token, then they input this information through the API to upload to their container. The following is a snippet of my code, where "container" is the container name and "accessKey" is the SAS token they submit:

```html
var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body);
var boundary = multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']);
var parts = multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);  

const sasURL = "https://myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/" + container + "?" + accessKey;
const containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(sasURL);
const blobName = parts[0].filename;
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
const uploadBlobReponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(parts[0].data, parts[0].data.length);
```

Azure states that uploadBlobResponse is declared but its value is never read, but I don't know how to fix that issue.

Comment: Your code looks ok. What are the issues you are running into?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, when I try to upload a file the webpage returns a HTTP 500 error.

Comment: Please wrap your code in try/catch block and check the exact error. I believe you are getting the error in your upload code. Since you are not catching the error, your function is throwing 500 error.

Comment: I checked the exact error using your idea, and it helped me figure out that my error was with the BlobContainerClient, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using a try/catch block to explicitly see what issues were in the code I found out that my BlobServiceClient was not properly defined. I created the blobServiceClient as a new BlobServiceClient first, then I created a new containerClient. The new upload code is shown below.

```js
 
const sasURL = "https://myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/" + container + "?" + accessKey;
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(sasURL);
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(container);
const blobName = parts[0].filename;
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
const uploadBlobReponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(parts[0].data, parts[0].data.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be getting 500 error due to authentication issue/sas url.
I have referred this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser) for creating CORS rule and SAS URL. Create the Javascript project and install the listed packages in the document.

**Packages**:

```
npm install @azure/storage-blob
npm install parcel
```

**index.js file:**

```
const { BlobServiceClient } =  require("@azure/storage-blob");
const  selectButton  =  document.getElementById("select-button");
const  fileInput  =  document.getElementById("file-input");
const  blobSasUrl  =  "your SAS URL";
const  blobServiceClient  =  new  BlobServiceClient(blobSasUrl);
const  containerName  =  "container name";
const  containerClient  =  blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const  uploadFiles  =  async () => {
try {
const  promises  = [];
for (const  file  of  fileInput.files) {
const  blockBlobClient  =  containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(file.name);
promises.push(blockBlobClient.uploadData(file));
}
await  Promise.all(promises);
alert("Done.");
}
catch (error) {
alert(error.message);
}
}
selectButton.addEventListener("click", () =>     fileInput.click());
fileInput.addEventListener("change", uploadFiles);
```

**index.html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html>
<body>
<button  id="select-button">Select and upload files</button>
<input  type="file"  id="file-input"  multiple  style="display: none;"  />
<script  type="module"  src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**package.json:**

```
{
"name": "blob-quickstart-v12",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "parcel ./index.html"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"browserslist": [
"last 1 Edge version",
"last 1 Chrome version",
"last 1 Firefox version",
"last 1 safari version",
"last 1 webkit version"
],
"dependencies": {
"@azure/storage-blob": "^12.12.0",
"parcel": "^2.8.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"buffer": "^5.7.1"}
}
```

**SAS URL** :
[image]
**Console:**
[image]

I copied the `URL` and paste it in the browser which gives below page
[image]

Upload a file. once successfully uploaded, it will show `done`
[image]

[image]

Go to the storage account, to see the uploaded file
[image]

Comment: Thank you, the index.js file helped me figure out my exact issue in my code. To fix it, I created the blobServiceClient as a separate new BlobServiceClient, then I defined containerClient as blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(container). This worked for me.